# launchd to run and hide an application

Tags: objective-c, launchd

So I have an application 'myApp', and I have a preference to load 'myApp' at login.
I have this all running fine via launchd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.myAppDomain.myApp</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
        <string>/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp</string>
      </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I would also like to give the user the option of also hiding 'myApp'

I tried creating a bash script, and adding to the ProgramArguments array in my lauchd plist:

```
#!/bin/sh

osascript=/usr/bin/osascript

$osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "'myApp'" to false'

exit 0
```

but this either fails to run, or it more likely runs before my app has had a chance to initialise.

Is there an easier way to do this that I am simply overlooking?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set a bool in your preference plist by calling

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HideOnLaunch"];
```

when the user chooses to hide your app on launch.

Then, when your app is launched via launchd, your app itself can check the `HideOnLaunch` setting in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, and hide itself accordingly:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HideOnLaunch"]){
     [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:nil];
}
```

Don't let `launchd` to hide your app!

Another approach would be the following: You can easily pass an argument to a Cocoa program. As described in [this `NSUserDefaults` document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Concepts/DefaultsDomains.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000718-BBCFDGFC), if you launch a Cocoa app like this:

```
AnApp.app/Contents/MacOS/AnApp -FuBar YES
```

Then you can get the value `YES` via `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FuBar"]`.

So, depending on the user's preference, you can write a `launchd` plist setting an argument `-HideOnLaunch YES` or `-HideOnLaunch NO`.

So, in your app delegate, presumably in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, hide your app depending on whether the program argument
 `HideOnLaunch` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuji.

I ended up with a launched plist like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myAppDomain.MyApp</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -hideOnLogin YES</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I added the bash script as strings in the ProgramArguments key, as Apple does in the following plist:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.FTMonitor.plist
```

the hideOnLogin key is only accessible through the launchd plist, and is reset when myApp is quit. I have a checkbox bound to another key "hideOnLoad", and when this is changed, I rewrite the launched plist to either:

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -hideOnLogin YES
```

or

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

depending on the circumstances.

On startup I then check to see if both defaults are true, if they are, I hide myApp, like so:
    [NSApp hide:self];

thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!